# order count of Customer_id by posts for category no

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have mysql table with Customer id's and post by the customer for various categories.I would like to find out for each category the count of customer post in descending order.

```
Customer id     Category no
1                 1
2                 1
3                 1
1                 1
1                 2
1                 1
2                 1
```

Basically in the table above customer id 1 has highest post for 1 then 2 then 3.
So what mysql query should I use to get the solution .

I really appreciate any help .Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the desired output?  I find the description of the results ambiguous -- do you want a list of categories in descending order or a list of customers within categories in descending order?

Comment: You need to `group by` 2 columns

Comment: @GordonLinoff list of highest contributing customers for that category

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you number of post entries in categories table grouped by categories and customers and ordered by their count in desending order:

```
select customer_id, category_no, count(1) as total_post
from category  
group by customer_id, category_no 
order by count(1) desc;
```

Comment: basicaly I want customer_ids : list of highest contributing customers for that category

Comment: where should i have to add where condition : WHERE category_no='1'

Comment: @json, between `from` and `group by` clauses.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT customer_id, COUNT(*) FROM category GROUP BY customer_id, category_no
```

Group by your 2 columns

Comment: where should i have to add where condition : WHERE category_no='1'

Answer (score 1):

To get the highest contributing customer for each category, you can do this:

```
select category_no, max(cnt) as maxcnt,
       substring_index(group_concat(customer_id order by cnt desc)) as cust3
from (select category_no, customer_id, count(*) as cnt
      from category
      group by category_no, customer_id
     ) c
group by category_no;
```